# Fixing/cleaning user-provided URLs via Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, clean-urls

Does anyone happen to have javascript code focused on cleaning up user-provided URLs?  I have a mobile app that asks users to enter their website URL, and many times the URLs are not properly formatted, lack the http:// prefix, etc.  (Typing on mobile tends to be error prone)  I often see stuff like:

```
google.com
ww.google.com
http//www.goggle.com
http://www..google.com
```

I know there'd be a certain amount of assuming one would have to do to clean a URL, but it just seems like there would be a library out there somewhere for URL cleaning?

Comment: There's no magic, all you have to do is a bunch of `if` and `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is as best of a start as you can get.
It now deals with: .co.uk or whatever multi-part domain types, protocol, www-less, protocol-less etc. I plan to make it a library plugin.

https://github.com/WebSudosUK/framework/blob/master/com.websudos.urlMatcher.js

Comment: Those are some great tips - I never thought about validating the top level domain against a fixed list.  I like your approach - if there is nothing canned out there, I'll take a shot at it.  Perhaps it'll give me a reason to contribute to github.  :)

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic!  :)  I'll give it a try!  Thanks Alex.  I might also try to add in some concept of error detection, like "Did you mean www.google.com?" if someone were to use something that is possible but unlikely, like "www.google.cm"  I'm trying to eliminate whatever user input errors I can.

Comment: I finally got around to implementing this - it worked perfect out of the box!  Nice shot, sir!

Comment: While testing with some of the bad URLs from my logs I found a few URLs that the code malforms.  http://mysubdomain.company.com Will turn to http://.company.com" and "http//www.company,com" will become blank.  Is it hard to compensate for those scenarios?  (Perhaps not the ",com" issue - I can see how that one would be an oddity.  But subdomains are pretty common)